# Unexpected token, expected ,

Tags: react-native

the error that is thrown out is: `Unexpected token, expected ,` at line 2 and word no. 21 according to this code. However I have no idea what it is talking about:

```
      {!cookies.get('loggedIn') ? (
      {window.location.href === "http://localhost:3000/" ? (
        <MenuItem
          primaryText="Sign Up"
          containerElement={<Link to="/signup" />}
          rightIcon={<LoginIcon />}
        />
      ) : (
        <MenuItem
          primaryText="Login"
          containerElement={<Link to="/" />}
          rightIcon={<LoginIcon />}
        />
    )}) : null}
```

Comment: Are you getting this in Android only? If so what is the return value of this and mention it's return type?   !cookies.get('loggedIn')

Comment: @AshwinMothilal this all comes in render()

Comment: Can you try rendering it like this "!!!cookies.get('loggedIn')" with three Not.

Comment: @AshwinMothilal Why? What is the reason behind it?

Comment: if cookies.get('loggedIn') returns a type string, it will throw error in Android like we're rendering text outside view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have extra `null` in your code.

Try this:

```
!cookies.get('loggedIn') ? (
      window.location.href === "http://localhost:3000/" ? (
        <MenuItem
          primaryText="Sign Up"
          containerElement={<Link to="/signup" />}
          rightIcon={<LoginIcon />}
        />
      ) : (
        <MenuItem
          primaryText="Login"
          containerElement={<Link to="/" />}
          rightIcon={<LoginIcon />}
        />
      )
   ) : null
```

or, you can also do this:

```
!cookies.get('loggedIn') && (
      window.location.href === "http://localhost:3000/" ? (
        <MenuItem
          primaryText="Sign Up"
          containerElement={<Link to="/signup" />}
          rightIcon={<LoginIcon />}
        />
      ) : (
        <MenuItem
          primaryText="Login"
          containerElement={<Link to="/" />}
          rightIcon={<LoginIcon />}
        />
      )
 )
```

because simple code is elegant :)